# I do not want to map all my xhtml pages by a controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

But I want to use Spring security.
I think i have to use `DispatcherServlet` and its configuration in web.xml

I am developing an application that is nor jsp nor jsf project, i am going to make all connection based on javascript/ajax/jquery via server communication.

Thus i do not want to map my xhtml pages to a controller.

But i have a single controller with `@RequestMapping(/auth/login)` i only want it to run when i request /auth/login this is not the problem, it is working excellently.

But when i use

spring
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

        contextConfigLocation
        
                classpath:META-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        
    
1

spring
/heythere/*

and call `http://localhost:8080/app/myhtml.xhtml` it tells me i have no mapping for this uri.

I do not want mapping, nor controller to run, only want to see the page.

But DispatcherServlet needs to map it, how can i tell DispatcherServlet not to map ordinary xhtml pages?

Comment: It's not really very clear what your question is. When you say "I think i have to use `DispatcherServlet`" do you mean that you have to use it because you want to use Spring Security? If so, that's not the case. You can use Spring Security with any Java web application. It doesn't have to be using Spring MVC.

Comment: @lukeTaylor thanks for answer. Can i use spring security without using DispatcherServlet?

Comment: Yes, you can use it without DispatcherServlet.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Inside your spring web mvc application context XML you should put something like:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/myhtml.xhtml"/>
```

The downside is you'll have to do this per page.

**Option 2:**

Use a Resource Handler:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources -->
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/static/**"/>
```

Your page would be visible like `http://localhost:8080/app/static/myhtml.xhtml`.

More info can be found in [Spring's Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources).